# plot_predict - error AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_prediction'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, time-series, statsmodels, arima

I ru both codes below python and get similar errors

```
model_fit.plot_predict(dynamic=False)
plt.show()

Error:AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'plot_predict'

plot_predict(model_fit, dynamic=False)
plt.show()

Error: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_prediction'

Name: statsmodels
Version: 0.14.0
```

Any ideas?

google! nothign works

Comment: Please post your full code.

Comment: I've fit my ARIMA Model
      
model = ARIMA(train, order=(0,1,2))
model_fit = model.fit
results = model.fit()
print(results.summary())

Comment: Dep. Variable:               Quantity   No. Observations:                   33
Model:                 ARIMA(0, 1, 2)   Log Likelihood                -369.461
Date:                Tue, 30 Jan 2024   AIC                            744.923
Time:                        11:55:57   BIC                            749.320
Sample:                    01-31-2015   HQIC                           746.380
                         - 09-30-2017                                         
Covariance Type:                  opg

Comment: coef              std err         z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
ma.L1         -0.3438      0.102     -3.360      0.001      -0.544      -0.143
ma.L2          0.3288      0.119      2.764      0.006       0.096       0.562
sigma2      5.604e+08   1.45e-11   3.85e+19      0.000     5.6e+08     5.6e+08

Comment: now i want to plot the predictions

model_fit.plot_predict(dynamic=False)
plt.show()

but got this error:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[221], line 1
----> 1 model_fit.plot_predict(dynamic=False)
      2 plt.show()

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'plot_predict'

Comment: edit your question with the code instead of putting it into comments, so it's easier to read. AFAIC `model_fit = model.fit` is missing the call `()`, use `model_fit = model.fit()`